# how to setup a cron job and using the proper syntax in my jobs

Tags: cron

I want to make a cron job that creates a tar of my web directory.

I have this job in place

```
* * * * * tar -zcvfp /disk1/archives/websites/`date +%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M-%S-%p`/`date +%Y-%m-%d_%I:%M:%S:%p`.tar.gz /web
```

this job SHOULD (but doesn't) create a tar file to my /disk1... directory. so I'm stumped on that one.

another thing that has been on my mind is, is it possible to make all backup tar file get dumped into a `date +%Y-%m-%d` and have all files that were created on that same day be placed there?

So an output would look like

`/disk1/archives/websites/2012-02-05/2012-02-05_5:25:04.tar.gz`

I have made this job run every minute for test purposes.

Is there anything wrong with my syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cron` does not know what `tar` or `date` is because it doesn't have environment variables. Reffer to the binaries using their full path.

If you don't know the full path, use `which` to get it.

Ex:

```
[bart@dev ~]$ which tar
/bin/tar
[bart@dev ~]$ which date
/bin/date
```

This would make your cron-line this:

```
/bin/tar -zcvfp /disk1/archives/websites/`/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d_%I-%M-%S`/`/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d_%I:%M:%S`.tar.gz /web
```

Comment: thanks, ya its late... i need sleep, your 100% right. I forgot to insert the path of the command i'm trying to run.

Answer (score 0):

Put your tar inside a shell script, say, `/usr/local/bin/backup.sh`.  Then call that script from cron.

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/backup.sh
```

The trick is that cron is not a shell, so things that work in shell expansion may not work in crontabs.  It's much, much safer and easier to debug to put your commands into a script, and then call that script (by it's full path).

Comment: You would still need to include full paths to binaries or but `bash` in front of your script so it would load a shell for it.